# Knockout-Kendo MultiSelect: Enter Key Clears Previously Selected Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-kendo

I'm  using the Knockout-Kendo MultiSelect control. If I select a value from the list, then type in the second value and click enter, the previously entered values are removed.

VIEW

```
<select data-bind="kendoMultiSelect: { data: choices, value: selectedChoice }"></select>
Selected: <strong data-bind="text: selectedChoice"> </strong>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
var ViewModel = function() {
this.choices = ko.observableArray(["apple", "orange", "banana"]);
this.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

There is a working example on the Knockout-Kendo Site.
[HERE](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/MultiSelect.html)

See the Fiddle below:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caine0323/r534hp6k/)

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with knockout-kendo being incompatible with kendo starting with 2015 Q1.   

https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to a co-worker for finding this!

There's a compatibility issue with this version of Kendo (V.2015.1.429) and Knockout-Kendo.

Apparently this is a known issue: 
[Here](https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/issues/202)

**QUICK FIX** (Custom Binding):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.multiSelect = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());

        options.change = function (e) {
            valueAccessor().value(e.sender.value());
        }

        $(element).kendoMultiSelect(options);
        var multiselect = $(element).data("kendoMultiSelect");    

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            multiselect.destroy();
        });
    }
};
```

Working Example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caine0323/89c1mpj7/2/)